# difference between core.c and pci.c in Linux nvme driver

Tags: linux, driver, pci, nvme

I want to learn how nvme driver works in Linux,

So I look into nvme driver source code [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.10.6/source/drivers/nvme/host)

what confuses me is that there are two source file containing **"module_init()"**

core.c

```
module_init(nvme_core_init);
```

and
pci.c

```
module_init(nvme_init);
```

I know the **module_init()** function is the entry of the driver

**but how come there are two entry in nvme driver** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`module_init()` is the entry point of a *module*, and with [abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction) we layer the modules to logically separate functionality, improve code reuse, etc...

- [`pci.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.10.6/source/drivers/nvme/host/pci.c) provides the PCI / PCIe interface/abstraction layer for using NVMe devices over a PCI bus - it has much more to do with managing tangible devices:

  - [`nvme_id_table`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.10.6/source/drivers/nvme/host/pci.c#L2095)
  - [`nvme_probe()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.10.6/source/drivers/nvme/host/pci.c#L1908)
  - [`nvme_irq()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.10.6/source/drivers/nvme/host/pci.c#L730)
- [`core.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.10.6/source/drivers/nvme/host/pci.c) provides the *core* driver for generically dealing with an NVMe devices connected to the system (it doesn't care *how*). This module cares more about providing the standardised block device access, etc...

  - [`nvme_fops`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.10.6/source/drivers/nvme/host/core.c#L1054)
  - [`nvme_submit_io()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.10.6/source/drivers/nvme/host/core.c#L673)

This is a common idiom throughout the kernel, and is done so that if an NVMe device became accessible via another bus, then `core.c` would be reused with no / minimal changes, and `new_bus.c` would be written to interface between the two.

---

If you're using NVMe over PCIe, then the following chain will hopefully help things make sense:

1. `pci.c` implements [`nvme_pci_reg_read32()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.10.6/source/drivers/nvme/host/pci.c#L1852)
2. `pci.c` registers `nvme_pci_reg_read32()` in the `nvme_ctrl_ops` structure, named [`nvme_pci_ctrl_ops`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.10.6/source/drivers/nvme/host/pci.c#L1880)
3. `core.c` implements [`nvme_init_ctrl()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.10.6/source/drivers/nvme/host/core.c#L1977), which is called with a pointer to one of these structures
4. `core.c` [keeps a reference](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.10.6/source/drivers/nvme/host/core.c#L1988) to the structure
5. `core.c` implements [`nvme_init_identify()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.10.6/source/drivers/nvme/host/core.c#L1204), which needs assistance of the lower-level - `pci.c`
6. `core.c` calls `pci.c`'s `nvme_pci_reg_read32()` via the [reference retained above](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.10.6/source/drivers/nvme/host/core.c#L1211)

If we were to develop a new bus that could support an NVMe device, then we could swap out `pci.c` for `new_bus.c` with no changes to `core.c` (as mentioned above).

---

It's also worth checking out the [`Kconfig`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.10.6/source/drivers/nvme/host/Kconfig) files as they can hint at things like this - though there is a certain amount of mental gymnastics to tie the source files to the menu options via the `Makefile`s.